# Compute the index from mouse position

Tags: c, winapi

I have this board(0,0 is top left):

[image]

and lets say that a block is LABEL_SIZE height and width.
and lets say that the red and blue dots are mouse click.
and i have an 2 - dimension array for this board, and i want to access to the cell 
where i clicked with the mouse (blue or red dots). so its look like simple logic to just
compute ptCursor.x / LABEL_SIZE to access to the column, and ptCursor.y / LABEL_SIZE to the row. but when i try this it addressing to another cell (like miles away).

What's wrong?

```
#define LABEL_SIZE 40
#define XLOCATION  ptCursor.x / LABEL_SIZE
#define YLOCATION  ptCursor.y / LABEL_SIZE

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ptCursor.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        ptCursor.y = HIWORD(lParam);
        return 0;

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (wParam >= VK_NUMPAD0 && wParam <= VK_NUMPAD9)
    {
        wsprintf(szWndText, szFormat, wParam - VK_NUMPAD0);
        SetWindowText(hwndLabels[XLOCATION][YLOCATION],
                      szWndText);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `hwndLabels[YLOCATION][XLOCATION]`?  Normally 2D arrays in C are row major, so you'd want the y index first.

Comment: Hard to see the connection between a keyboard event and a mouse event you are looking for.  What do you expect to happen when the user never moves the mouse and presses a key?

Comment: Please define "miles away".  Is it a valid cell, or is it a HUGE number?

Comment: Thx Carl Norum, that was the mistake..

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx

It advises you NOT to use the `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` macros to extract the cursor position.

If your system has multiple monitors, the co-ordinates can be negative, and those macros will not handle it.  Instead, use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM`.

Comment: Thank you for mention it, i will used it from now on,,